# Returning Boolean Value for __str__ Method

Tags: python, class, methods, boolean

I am trying to write a `__str__` method for a "Card" class which takes a rank and a suit. I would like for the method to take (for example) "j" to return "Jack"  Here is what I have so far:

```
def __init__(self,rank,suit):
    '''Rank represents the number on the card (Ace-King). Suit represents the type on each card
       (Hearts,Diamonds,Spades,Clubs)'''

    self.r = rank
    self.s = suit

def __str__(self):
    '''Creates a string for appropriate display of cards'''

    if isinstance(self.r,int) == False:

        if self.r == "J" or "j":
            return self.r == "Jack"
        if self.r == "Q" or "q":
            return self.r == "Queen"
        if self.r == "K" or "k":
            return self.r == "King"
        if self.r == "A" or "a":
            return self.r == "Ace"

    if self.s == "D" or "d":
        return self.s == "Diamonds"
    if self.s == "H" or "h":
        return self.s == "Hearts"
    if self.s == "S" or "s":
        return self.s == "Spades"
    if self.s == "C" or "c":
        return self.s == "Clubs"

    return str(self.r) + " " + "of" + " " + str(self.s)
```

I am being returned with: `TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type bool)`

Comment: Have you tried returning a `str`?

Comment: `if self.r == "J" or "j":` will always be `True`, because `"j"` as a string evaluates to `True`. You're probably looking for `if self.r == "J" or self.r == "j"`. Furthermore, instead of `if isinstance(self.r, int) == False`, just say `if not isinstance(self.r, int)`.

Comment: You probably misunderstood the meaning of `return` since you are using it to assign values to variables. Simply use `self.s = 'Jack'` when assigning. Only the last use of `return` is correct, i.e. when you really want to get out of the function and return a value.

Answer (score 2):

All your return statements are something of the order of

```
return a == b
```

So they return True if a equals b, and False otherwise. Whenever it encounters a `return` statement, it will return from the function and not execute anything else.

I am not quite sure of what you try to achieve, but this isn't going to cut it.

Maybe something like this:

```
def __init__(self, rank, suit):
    self.r = str(rank).lower()
    self.s = suit.lower()
    assert(self.r in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'j', 'q', 'k', 'a'])
    assert(self.s in ['d', 's', 'c', 'h'])


def __str__(self):
    '''Creates a string for appropriate display of cards'''

    rank_converter = {
        'j': 'Jack',
        'q': 'Queen',
        'k': 'King',
        'a': 'Ace'
    }
    for i in range(1, 11):
        rank_converter[str(i)] = str(i)

    suit_converter = {
        'd': 'Diamonds',
        'h': 'Hearts',
        's': 'Spades',
        'c': 'Clubs'
    }

    return rank_converter[self.r] + ' of ' suit_converter[self.s]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few errors going on:

- `if self.r == "J" or "j"`, and similar lines, does NOT mean "if `self.r` contains either `"J"` or `"j"`". Python will parse it as: `if (self.r == "J") or ("j")` -- two separate conditions. The second condition there will always be `True`, because any non-empty string (such as `"j"`) casts to `True`. What you really want is something like `if self.r == "J" or self.r == "j"`.
- When you're trying to give the full-name strings, you're accidentally returning a boolean. The line `return self.r == "Jack"`, for example, reads as: "Return `True` if `self.r` contains `"Jack"`; otherwise, return `False`." You don't want to be returning anything here.

The following code should work right, and hopefully is readable and understandable. See if you can follow what each line is saying.

```
    def __str__(self):
        '''Creates a string for appropriate display of cards'''
        if not isinstance (self.r, int): # Cleaner than '== False'
            if self.r == "J" or self.r == "j":
                r = "Jack"
            elif self.r == "Q" or self.r == "q":
                r = "Queen"
            elif self.r == "K" or self.r == "k":
                r = "King"
            elif self.r == "A" or self.r == "a":
                r = "Ace"
        else:
            r = str(self.r)

        if self.s == "D" or self.s == "d":
            s = "Diamonds"
        elif self.s == "H" or self.s == "h":
            s = "Hearts"
        elif self.s == "S" or self.s == "s":
            s = "Spades"
        elif self.s == "C" or self.s == "c":
            s = "Clubs"

        return r + " of " + s
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `if var == 'a' or 'b'` doesn't do what you think it does. It will always be `True`, since the non-empty string `'b'` is `True`.

Second, you're creating an incorrect `__str__()` method. It needs to return a `str`, not a `bool`. That's why it's telling you that making it return a `bool` is an error. Instead of `return self.r == "Jack"`, just do `return "Jack"`. Better yet, you should make the value of `self.r` something like `2` or `"Jack"` and `self.s` something like `"Hearts"` (if they aren't already), and then you can just define this:

```
def __str__():
    return str(self.r) + ' of ' + self.s
```

That's what the `__str__()` method is supposed to do: return a nice, human-readable description of the object like `"2 of Hearts"` instead of something like `<Card object at 0x0000000002B249B0>`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to (for example) `return "Jack"` instead of `return self.r == "Jack"`. The former is returning a string, the latter (what you're doing) is returning the result of `thing == thing`, which is a boolean.

---

Edit: My commenters are correct; in order to return a suit and rank you should create some local variables. Perhaps something like

```
if self.r in ["J", "j"]:
    rank = "Jack"
    etc.

if self.s in ["D", "d"]:
    suit = "Diamonds"
    etc.

return str(rank) + " " + "of" + " " + str(suite)
```

Comment: Yes, he's accidentally returning a boolean instead of a string, but he's also looking for a full card-name -- so not just `return "Jack"`, but also including the suit name.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I've edited my answer to suggest using local vars to hold on to that till the return.